# Get 2nd parent directory of given file

Tags: regex, powershell, substring

I have a script which finds files containing certain strings.

Let's say my found file is:

```
C:\temp\drivers\etc\file.INF
```

I want to get the 2nd parent folder for that file.

For example if it's:

```
C:\temp\drivers\etc\file.INF
```

I want to have this path:

```
C:\temp\drivers
```

What makes the most sense to you in a situation like this?

I can make it work with:

```
$test = "C:\temp\drivers\etc\file.INF" 
$first_parent = Split-path $test -Parent
$second_parent= $first_parent.Substring(0,$first_parent.LastIndexOf('\'))
$second_parent
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\drivers
```

But is it optimal?

Comment: Just use `Split-Path` twice: `$second_parent = Split-Path $first_parent -Parent`. Alternatively, if `$test` is a file you know exists, you could do something like this: `(Get-Item $test).Directory.Parent.FullName`.

Comment: Of course! Brain a bit fried today, much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your item is a file - not just a string - you can derive the grandparent dir from the `fileinfo` object that you get from `Get-Item` or `Get-ChildItem`. like this ...

```
$FileName_String = 'C:\temp\drivers\etc\file.INF'
# fake reading in the fileinfo object
#    in real life, use Get-Item or Get-ChildItem
$FileName_FileInfoObject = [System.IO.FileInfo]$FileName_String

$2ndParentDir = $FileName_FileInfoObject.Directory.Parent

$FileName_String
$FileName_FileInfoObject.FullName
$2ndParentDir.FullName
```

output ...

```
C:\temp\drivers\etc\file.INF
C:\temp\drivers\etc\file.INF
C:\temp\drivers
```

if it is just a string, then you need to use `Split-Path` twice. [*grin*]

Comment: Cheers Lee, much appreciated.

Comment: @Rakha - you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Using split-path twice gets it done. Easiest way is piping it :

```
$test = "C:\temp\drivers\etc\file.INF"
Split-path $test | split-path
```

Output:

```
C:\temp\drivers
```